# Flutter emulator > java.io.IOException: Failed to generate v1 signature

Tags: android, flutter

When I tried to run android emulator with Flutter app, It doesn't work in `vs code`.

It throws error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
   > java.io.IOException: Failed to generate v1 signature

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
```

People said in case of this error, I need to delete `~/.android/debug.keystore`.

But I use debug.keystore key in another project with `android studio`, so I can't delete this keystore.

Then I couldn't find any way to run emulator of flutter app.

How can I make this emulator work? Please help me..!